# WPF. Use button style which is in xaml in code behind

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, styles, code-behind

I create button behind code and now have to use Style which is in xaml, how can I call that style in c# for my button?

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            this.Loaded += OnLoaded;
        }

        private void OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs routedEventArgs)
        {

           var button1 = new Button();

            TestPanel.Children.Add(button1);
        }
    }
}
```

Style is `<Style x:Key="ButtonStyle"  TargetType="{x:Type Button}">`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just set it:

```
Style myStyle = (Style)Resources["ButtonStyle"];
button1.Style = myStyle;
```

Note that items coming out of the `Resources` dictionary must be cast to their actual type.

That being said, you *shouldn't* be creating controls in code-behind. In 99.99% of  cases you should be doing this in XAML and assigning the style there.